# How do we predict the lifespan of dinosaurs?

Tags: zoology, palaeontology, lifespan

Of course, they are fossils now. I found a link [here](http://www.theguardian.com/science/2009/feb/07/dinosaur-lifespan) which states that herbivors lived far longer than carnivores. The example being a T-Rex being "old" at 29, and a herbivorous Bothriospondylus having not reached half it's adult size at 43 years old.

But, is there any evidence that can indicate their life spans, or life spans of at least one kind of the dinosaurs?

An additional brief question is are their lifespans comparable with modern day descendants?

Comment: @questionhang: The general technique with dinosaurs is to count the rings in bones, although there are limitations to the method. Most notably, the technique gives an estimate of how old an individual was at death, not how long a member of the species could survive per se. Nevertheless, see https://books.google.com.au/books?id=9zRMBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=ageing+dinosaurs+by+bone+rings&source=bl&ots=jOlKtu8vsK&sig=BjNoZxlMkPwF763PdWSUqYjEigI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi82dKSitvJAhUkGqYKHTneCeAQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=ageing%20dinosaurs%20by%20bone%20rings&f=false

Comment: The question is unclear. 1) Are you talking about dinosaurs or mammals? 2) What dinosaur are you talking about? 3) Are you interested in estimates of age or description of the methods to find these ages (as suggested in the comments). Note also that you end sentences who are not questions with question marks which is quite confusing.

Comment: @Remi.b The description is better now?

Comment: I have made some major edits to the question and retracted my close vote. In it's current state the question is very answerable since the question is now asking about a general technique (hinted at by @bshane's comment).

Comment: I also don't find the question particularly unclear in its current form - voting to keep open.